# Creating abstract enemy state machines in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, subclass, game-development

I'm trying to implement a reusable finite state machine for enemy behaviors in my game and am struggling to figure out how to pass derived classes as parameters. Below are the two base template classes I have for the different States that enemies can have as well as the State Managers that act as the context in the finite state machine implementation. The State Manager scripts are attached to the enemy game objects and should contain common behaviors and data used by all enemies.

```
public class EnemyState : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected float stateStartTime;

    public virtual void EnterState(EnemyStateManager enemy)
    {
        stateStartTime = Time.time;
    }

    public virtual void ExitState(EnemyStateManager enemy) {}

    public virtual void UpdateState(EnemyStateManager enemy) {}
}
```

```
public class EnemyStateManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected EnemyState currentState;
    public float health;

    public virtual void Start() {}

    void Update()
    {
        currentState.UpdateState(this);
    }

    public void SwitchState(EnemyState newState)
    {
        currentState.ExitState(this);
        currentState = newState;
        currentState.EnterState(this);
    }

    public virtual void Attack() {}

    public virtual void Die() {}

    public virtual bool CheckWall() {}

    public virtual bool CheckLedge() {}

    public void SetVelocity(float speed) {}
}
```

My intention is to then create concrete classes that derive from the above classes to speed up designing different enemy AI behavior so that I don't have to rewrite common enemy logic that is already contained in the base template and can be reused between different types of enemies.

```
public class SoldierStateManager : EnemyStateManager
{
    public SoldierIdleState IdleState = new SoldierIdleState();
    public SoldierDeadState UnconsciousState = new SoldierUnconsciousState();

    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();

        currentState = IdleState;
        currentState.EnterState(this);
    }
}
```

```
public class SoldierIdleState : EnemyState
{
    float moveSpeed = 2f;

    public override void EnterState(SoldierStateManager soldier) 
    {
        base.EnterState(soldier);
        soldier.SetVelocity(moveSpeed);
    }

    public override void ExitState(SoldierStateManager soldier) 
    {
        base.ExitState(soldier);
    }

    public override void UpdateState(SoldierStateManager soldier) 
    {
        base.UpdateState(soldier);
        if (soldier.health <= 0)
        {
            soldier.SwitchState(soldier.UnconsciousState);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class SoldierUnconsciousState : EnemyState
{
    float moveSpeed = 0f;
    float unconsciousDuration = 5f;

    public override void EnterState(SoldierStateManager soldier) 
    {
        base.EnterState(soldier);
        soldier.SetVelocity(moveSpeed);
    }

    public override void ExitState(SoldierStateManager soldier) 
    {
        base.ExitState(soldier);
    }

    public override void UpdateState(SoldierStateManager soldier) 
    {
        base.UpdateState(soldier);
        if (Time.time >= stateStartTime + unconsciousDuration)
        {
            soldier.SwitchState(soldier.IdleState);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm stuck because when I try to implement the idea above, I get errors in the concrete State classes such as:
`'SoldierIdleState.EnterState(SoldierStateManager)': no suitable method found to override`
in all the methods I attempt to override from the base class, I'm guessing because the method signature of `EnterState()` is expecting type `EnemyStateManager` and does not accept `SoldierStateManager` even though it is derived from `EnemyStateManager`.

Is there any way I can pass EnemyStateManager subclasses into the derived methods as I'm pretty new to C# and inheritance so any guidance on how I can make this work is appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of strange design choices. What is the purpose of this `currentState.UpdateState(this);` ? Since the State is derived from a MB, it already has access to an `Update()` function. If you want to reference the manager, and there is only one, you can singleton-ize it, otherwise, make a member variable pointing to it. Why is there `health;` in a state manager? Why are you calling `new` on MonoBehaviours: `IdleState = new SoldierIdleState();`. Why did you create an empty `Start`? Why are you overwriting function signatures of `EnterState` and `ExitState` in child classes?

Comment: Also, this `if (Time.time >= stateStartTime + unconsciousDuration)` will only work once. You should seriously rethink the design, research how MonoBehaviors work a little more and also look into ScriptableObjects.

Comment: The entire purpose of the design is to build a reusable and hierarchical Finite State Machine to enhance separation of concerns and not have to use repeated code in every script's Update() function and overwriting them to both have access to common logic stored in the parent class and have the flexibility of adding child-specific logic.

Comment: I also want `(Time.time >= stateStartTime + unconsciousDuration)` to only work once because it acts as a condition to transition from one state to another. I suggest looking into Finite State Machine designs to understand why I've went with the design choices above as opposed to using standard MonoBehavior scripting patterns.

Comment: I know about state machines, but you missed my point. My point is that is not how MBs work. Unity is not a C# engine. It is a C++ engine, so `new` doesn't work the way you think with a MB. There are also several native functions that are more efficient than using an `Update` call. My point was not about the state machine design, but your code design. When working with a framework, you need to adapt code to that framework. Therefore, a lot of what I said stands. Polymorphism is encouraged in C#, but SOs are preferred in Unity in certain situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got what I was looking for by removing the need to pass the state managers as parameters and instead passing them through the constructor. For some reason the constructor will accept the derived state manager class as a valid parameter and now any of the child state classes I create can access fields from SoldierStateManager.

```
public abstract class EnemyState
{
    protected EnemyStateManager entity;
    protected float stateStartTime;

    public EnemyState(EnemyStateManager enemy)
    {
        this.entity = enemy;
    }

    public virtual void EnterState()
    {
        stateStartTime = Time.time;
    }

    public virtual void ExitState() { }

    public virtual void UpdateState() { }
}
```

```
public class SoldierIdleState : EnemyState
{
    protected SoldierStateManager soldier;
    float moveSpeed = 2f;

    public SoldierIdleState(SoldierStateManager enemy) : base(enemy)
    {
        soldier = enemy;
    }
    public override void EnterState() 
    {
        base.EnterState(soldier);
        soldier.SetVelocity(moveSpeed);
    }

    public override void ExitState() 
    {
        base.ExitState();
    }

    public override void UpdateState() 
    {
        base.UpdateState(soldier);
        if (soldier.health <= 0)
        {
            soldier.SwitchState(soldier.UnconsciousState);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class SoldierStateManager : EnemyStateManager
{
    public SoldierIdleState IdleState { get; private set; }
    public SoldierUnconsciousState UnconsciousState { get; private set; }

    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();

        IdleState = new SoldierIdleState(this);
        UnconsciousState = new SoldierUnconsciousStateState(this);

        currentState = IdleState;
        currentState.EnterState();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `new` on Components is bad practice though. `AddComponent` should be used instead. Also, `Start` can be *protected* as there's no point to it being *public*.

Answer (score 0):

An override method must have the same signature as the overridden base method.

From your base class :

```
public virtual void EnterState(EnemyStateManager enemy)
```

From your child class :

```
public override void EnterState(SoldierStateManager soldier)
```

You need to keep `EnemyStateManager` as parameter type. On your use case's side, you'll indeed pass a parameter of `SoldierStateManager` type being given it inherits from `EnemyStateManager` and consequently is the expected type.

```
public override void EnterState(EnemyStateManager soldier)
```

Simple example of use case :

```
SoldierUnconsciousState test_case = new();
SoldierStateManager new_state = new();
test_case.EnterState(new_state); // new_state is both of type SoldierStateManager and EnemyStateManager
```

Comment: For the most part this does get rid of the error of having no suitable method found to override. However `public override void UpdateState(EnemyStateManager soldier)` will report that `'EnemyStateManager' does not contain a definition for 'UnconsciousState'` in `soldier.SwitchState(soldier.UnconsciousState)` since `UnconsciousState` is a state that is defined in `SoldierStateManager` instead of `EnemyStateManager`. How do I get keep `EnemyStateManager` in the method signature while allowing the method to access variables of its subclasses?

Comment: This is now a design issue more than a code issue. While not the smartest choice considering the whole thing, a quick fix would be to cast `soldier` to `SoldierStateManager` to access the child states you are looking for. You will stay with EnemyStateManager in the method signature since it is mandatory when overriding. Make sure the casting check is successful so you don't propagate any errors regarding your whole project (we don't know how everything interacts together).